# Why is my Java Applet showing a blank screen?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, applet

I'm currently working with java applets and java.awt.Graphics to execute a simple example. I've been looking at a provided example that should display a turtle, from there I can make various modifications and explore how graphics work. 

My issue is that when I run the program it displays a blank applet. At first I thought that the TortoiseRacerClient init and paint methods were not doing anything, but upon testing them both with basic print statements I found that they are both functional.

I assume that the issue is with one or several of my variables, but I'm not sure exactly where to look.

**Structure**
The Animal abstract superclass is inherited by the TortoiseRacer class
The Movable interface is implemented by the TortoiseRacer class
The TortoiseRacerClient class creates a TortoiseRacer instance and sets up the applet

**Code**
**-Animal Class**

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public abstract class Animal {
private int x;      // x position
private int y;      // y position
private String ID;  // animal ID

public Animal( )  { ID = ""; }
public Animal( String rID, int rX, int rY ) 
{ ID = rID; x = rX; y = rY;  }
public String getID( ) { return ID; }
public int getX( ) { return x; }
public int getY( ) { return y; }
public void setX( int newX ) { x = newX; }
public void setY( int newY ) { y = newY; }
public abstract void draw( Graphics g );
}
```

**-Moveable Class**

```
public interface Moveable {
int FAST = 5; // static constant
int SLOW = 1; // static constant

void move( ); // abstract method

}
```

**-TortoiseRacer Class**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class TortoiseRacer extends Animal implements Moveable  {
public TortoiseRacer( ) { super( ); }
public TortoiseRacer( String rID, int rX, int rY ) {
 super( rID, rX, rY );
}

public void draw( Graphics g ) {
 int startX = getX( );
 int startY = getY( );
 g.setColor( new Color( 34, 139, 34 ) ); // dark green
 //body
 g.fillOval( startX, startY, 25, 15 );
 //head
 g.fillOval( startX + 20, startY + 5,  15, 10 );
 //flatten bottom
  g.clearRect( startX, startY + 11, 35, 4 );
 //feet
 g.setColor( new Color( 34, 139, 34 ) );  // brown
 g.fillOval( startX + 3, startY + 10,  5, 5 );
 g.fillOval( startX + 17, startY + 10, 5, 5 );
 }

public void move( ) { setX( getX( ) + SLOW ); }
}
```

**-TortoiseRacerClient Class**

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

public class TortoiseRacerClient extends JApplet {
private TortoiseRacer t;

public void init( ) {
t = new TortoiseRacer( "Tortoise", 50, 50 );
System.out.print(t.getID());
}

public void paint( Graphics g ) {
for ( int i = 0; i < getWidth( ); i++ )
{
  t.move( );
  t.draw( g );

 //Pause.wait( .03 );
 g.clearRect( 0, 0, getWidth( ), getHeight( ) );
 System.out.print("I'm running");
}
}
}
```

**Problem**
My java applet is blank, could someone please explain why?
And perhaps point me in the right direction for what I'm trying to do (draw a turtle)?

**Notes**
Using Eclipse (Mars 4.5.2)
New to java.awt.Graphics and JApplet
As to why I'm doing this in the first place, it's an introductory assignment. We will eventually move on to JavaFx.

Comment: Side note: applets are somehow *dead end* technology. Unless your boss asks you too; there isn't too much sense in learning about them. Meaning: if you are interested in java GUI applications, consider looking into Swing or JavaFx instead.

Comment: Does your `clearRect` maybe clear your drawing always to fast?

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free).

Comment: `Paint` should paint the visual state of a object. Logic of moving objects have to be in separate thread or triggered from event handlers. Particularly is wrong to make loop with delays in `paint`.

Comment: @Kevin Wallis That might be it. I commented out the following code "Pause.wait( .03 );" because "Pause" was unresolved. Do you think that is the issue?

Comment: @CodeSmurf does it work without this code line?

Comment: @Kevin Wallis With it, I get the error "Pause cannot be unresolved". Without it, the applet is blank, probably because as you said the drawing clears away too fast. However I surrounded the wait() method with a try/catch block and the applet shows the turtle. However a.) I feel like that's a haphazard solution and b.) the turtle doesn't move.

Comment: I think in the `try catch` there is a exception catched. Have you added a library or where does `Pause` come from?

Comment: That's actually the main frustration. This was given as sample code and I don't know what Pause is. I've been looking at documentation for applets and graphics but I haven't found it yet.